# Substituting part of words in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Given this two text:

```
$mir1 = 'microRNA-9a';
$mir2 =  'microRNA10a';
$mir3 =  'microrna3a';
```

I want to change it to:

```
miR-9a
miR-10a
miR-3a
```

In principle I'd like to replace all the variation `microRNA` part with `miR-`
Is there any single regex to do that?

I tried this but not sure how to capture the digit part.

```
my $mirnew = $mir =~ s/microRNA(\d+)/miR-/gi;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture words, not digits after hyphen. To backreferecence to capture group, you use `$1`:

```
s/microRNA-?(\w+)/miR-$1/gi;
```

Comment: [Don't use `\1`, use `$1`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1).

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually need to capture anything, just case insensitively replace `microRNA` and an optional `-` with `miR-`:

```
s/microRNA-?/miR-/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\bmicrorna.*?([\d]+a)\b/miR-$1/ig
```